# Prestashop - Productos superpuestos en algunas categorias

Tags: php, html, prestashop

Me explico,esto solo ocurre en ciertos productos, por ejemplo los libros infantiles salen unos encima de otros pero en cambio las novelas de misterio aparecen correctamente bien listadas.

En teoría según funciona prestashop el código debería generarse para todos los productos, subcategorías,etc. de igual modo. Pero me encuentro que no es el caso por algún motivo que desconozco.

[image: imagen del error]

He detectado el siguiente código en los productos erroneos:
[image: codigo erroneo]

En cambio en los productos que aparecen correctamente listados el código es el siguiente:
[image: imagen codigo correcto]

Por algún motivo algo parece cambiar el código. Alguien me podría ayudar? Si se necesita algún dato extra o código o lo que sea por favor decirme y lo adjunto. Gracias!

Edit: he comprobado modulos sobre productos activandolos y desactivandolos y no parece haber ninguna diferencia.

También he probado el navegador edge y aparece el mismo error.

En la consola aparece un error 404 sin explicación alguna en las páginas donde el error sucede.

Adjunto un error con el modo depuración que aparece en la página principal que nose si tenga que ver ya que en las páginas donde aparece el error no se ve ningún error de depuración.

```html
(1/1) ContextErrorException
Notice: Undefined index: page_name

in b4511379b50029b1aefbe0f988e0ce2b2b738b93_2.file.widgets.tpl.php line 26
at content_6284bd1b711e05_09092335(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123
at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114
at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216
at Smarty_Internal_Template->render(false, 0)
in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 232
at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute(object(SmartyDevTemplate), null, null, null, 0)
in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 116
at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch(null, null, null, null, false, true, false)
in SmartyDevTemplate.php line 40
at SmartyDevTemplateCore->fetch()
in Module.php line 2449
at ModuleCore->display('/home/customer/www/web/public_html/modules/ybc_widget/ybc_widget.php', 'widgets.tpl')
in ybc_widget.php line 980
at Ybc_widget->hookDisplayTopColumn(array('smarty' => object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 1))
in Hook.php line 997
at HookCore::coreCallHook(object(Ybc_widget), 'hookDisplayTopColumn', array('smarty' => object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 1))
in Hook.php line 421
at HookCore::callHookOn(object(Ybc_widget), 'displayTopColumn', array('smarty' => object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 1))
in Hook.php line 934
at HookCore::exec('displayTopColumn', array('smarty' => object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 1), null)
in smarty.config.inc.php line 167
at smartyHook(array('h' => 'displayTopColumn'), object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in SmartyLazyRegister.php line 83
at SmartyLazyRegister->__call('smartyHook', array(array('h' => 'displayTopColumn'), object(SmartyDevTemplate)))
in c64ce3c9daf10776abfb493dd18de2f93c402c76_2.file.layout-both-columns.tpl.php line 83
at content_6284bd1b5249a4_86444704(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123
at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114
at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216
at Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
in smarty_internal_template.php line 385
at Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender('layouts/layout-both-columns.tpl', null, 'pureinlayouts/layout-left-column.tpl', 0, 3600, array(), 2, false, null, null)
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 116
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->endChild(object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'layouts/layout-both-columns.tpl')
in ec692eba82ce1b3b77b671dd4253dbc7717e5c2f_2.file.layout-left-column.tpl.php line 38
at content_6284bd1b4f46e8_05265934(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123
at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114
at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216
at Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
in smarty_internal_template.php line 385
at Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender('layouts/layout-left-column.tpl', null, 'pureinlayouts/layout-left-column.tpl', 0, 3600, array(), 2, false, null, null)
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 116
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->endChild(object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'layouts/layout-left-column.tpl')
in 1af4f488e5e25dd263067d1a94e0c9f1f5974397_2.file.page.tpl.php line 33
at content_6284bd1b4e4538_20076368(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123
at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114
at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216
at Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
in smarty_internal_template.php line 385
at Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender('page.tpl', null, 'pureinlayouts/layout-left-column.tpl', 0, 3600, array(), 2, false, null, null)
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 116
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->endChild(object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'page.tpl')
in 3e6091962cd37d43ae9bc3ae1f1f54a32b6808f6_2.file.index.tpl.php line 31
at content_6284bd1b4cdb46_30313824(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123
at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114
at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216
at Smarty_Internal_Template->render(false, 0)
in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 232
at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute(object(SmartyDevTemplate), null, 'pureinlayouts/layout-left-column.tpl', null, 0)
in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 116
at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('index.tpl', null, 'pureinlayouts/layout-left-column.tpl', null, false, true, false)
in SmartyDev.php line 40
at SmartyDev->fetch('index.tpl', null, 'pureinlayouts/layout-left-column.tpl')
in FrontController.php line 727
at FrontControllerCore->smartyOutputContent('index.tpl')
in FrontController.php line 709
at FrontControllerCore->display()
in Controller.php line 326
at ControllerCore->run()
in Dispatcher.php line 518
at DispatcherCore->dispatch()
in index.php line 28
```

Answer (score 2):

Hola ¿Que versión de prestashop estás usando?
¿La plantilla que tienes instalada es compatible?
¿Has estado editando algo de prestashop? Configuración, plantilla...
Creo recordar que $page_name cambió en la 1.7 por $page.page_name como variable para mostrar (por lo que veo del error)
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/controller/FrontController.php#L453

Comment: hola estamos en la versión 1.7.8.3 la plantilla es compatible con la versión, la compramos en la web oficial de prestashop, nos dió un error al colocarla por lo que pedimos soporte y nos ayudaron los desarrolladores a colocarla, desde entonces aparecen estos errores visuales. he intentado solucionar y colocar page.   donde estaba la variable page.page_name sin exito ninguno. Tampoco se si el error sea relevante respecto a los productos que se ven mal ya que el error aparece en otra pagina, es decir la principal.

Comment: Por experiencia, si tienes aún soporte con la plantilla lo comentes al desarrollador porque algo no está bien del todo o falta algo por activar. Ellos tendrán acceso al código y a tu proyecto. El error que tienes se analizaría mejor con el debug activo en la web, algo que le falte en el .tpl que muestra los productos